# Create dynamic line chart live data from mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I want to create a `dynamic line chart` based on `data coming from MySQL`. I am looking for the example so that if there is new data in MySQL, line chart would be updated without reloading the web page. Can anyone help me by providing an example for the problem that I described ? for non-binding chart types can be highcharts, chartjs, and so on. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For something like that to work you would first need a way of watching the db for changes. I don't know what technology you're using but there are plenty of libraries out there such as [mysql-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events) for node that do just that. To update the ui when new data gets inserted to mysql, you would need to use socket connections. For that I would check out [Socket.io](https://socket.io/).

In summary, you could have code that watched mysql for changes and when triggered would send out an event to all socket connections. Then in your ui, your code would listen for those events and act accordingly.